# Reference error when calling function in external library - firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, referenceerror

I am using [Geoplugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript) to retrieve data about the user sending a form to subscribe to a newsletter.

On Chrome and Safari it works well. On the other hand, Firefox yields a `ReferenceError: geoplugin_request is not defined`

Why does Firefox behave differently? How do I fix it? 
Thanks

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WEHMIX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stile.css">
    <!--<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>-->
    <script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
                <h1 class="title-box">wehmix</h1>
                <h3>Rimani in contatto con il progetto wehmix.</h3>
                <p>Iscriviti alla newsletter per essere aggiornato in anteprima sull'evoluzione del progetto, per partecipare agli incontri di presentazione e far parte della ricerca.</p>
                <form id="contatto" method="post" action="https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/proxy/https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/4790cf82-7131-46a1-b427-562e4e8f22ce/newsletter/subscriber">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci la tua e-mail" value="">
                    <input type="submit" value="Iscriviti">
                </form>
                <p class="feedback"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var request;

$("#contatto").submit(function(e){
    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }

    // Retrieve email
    var $email = $('#email').val();

    // Take data available from navigator object
    var $ip = geoplugin_request();
    var $browserCodeName = navigator.appCodeName;
    var $browserName = navigator.appName;
    var $browserVersion = navigator.appVersion;
    var $language = navigator.language;
    var $platform = navigator.platform;
    var $city = geoplugin_city();
    var $region = geoplugin_regionName();
    var $country = geoplugin_countryName();

    // Prova stampa valori geocode
    console.log($city);
    console.log($region);
    console.log($country);

    // Create the JSON structure
    var user = {};
    user['user_agent'] = {};

    user.email_address = $email;
    user.user_agent.ip = $ip;
    user.user_agent.browserCodeName = $browserCodeName;
    user.user_agent.browserName = $browserName;
    user.user_agent.browserVersion = $browserVersion;
    user.user_agent.language = $language;
    user.user_agent.platform = $platform;
    user.user_agent.city = $city;
    user.user_agent.region = $region;
    user.user_agent.country = $country;

    var finalJson = JSON.stringify(user);

    console.log(finalJson);

    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    //var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/proxy/https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/4790cf82-7131-46a1-b427-562e4e8f22ce/newsletter/subscriber",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: finalJson
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        $('.feedback').text('Iscrizione completata con successo!');
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+textStatus, errorThrown);
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a race condition. You load both, the geoplugin script and your own event handler. If the geoplugin needs to load longer than your own script and you are fast enough in submitting your form, it could be that the global `geoplugin_request` is not yet available. It seems strange that the script needs this much time, but with the own script locally available and the other elsewhere, it is possible.

Your tags say that you use jQuery, so you could load the geoplugin via the `$.getScript()` function and register the click handler in an anonymous function given as the second parameter:

```
$.getScript("http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp", function () {
  $("#contatto").submit(function(e){ ... }
});
```

A more elegant solution would be to use a module loader tool that handles dependencies like [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org).

Comment: I tried your solution, and while it works on Firefox it doesn't work anymore on Chrome! It yields the same error Firefox was yielding before this change..

Comment: That's strange. I tried to re-produce your problem by using https://jsfiddle.net, but got the problem that the geoplugin seems to not fully support encrypted connections (https) which is required by jsfiddle. It could not be loaded. Is your environment maybe on https as well?

Comment: Nope, but I think I figured it out. My issue probably has to do with Iceweasel, the Debian version of Firefox. Somehow it doesn't load the functions / variable from an external library, whereas the original Firefox works flawlessly. Thanks for your help anyway!